# How would I get my app to only logs the image URLs to the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I get my app to only logs the image URLs to the console? Im new to web development and im currently looking for experienced developers to assist me with the issue im having. PLEASE HELP!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```js
'use strict';

function getDogImage() {
  fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => 
      displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  //replace the existing image with the new one
  $('.results-img').replaceWith(
    `<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
  )
  //display the results section
  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getDogImage();
  });
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dog API Example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dog API: A Simple Example</h1>

        <form>
          <input type="submit" value="Get a dog pic!">
        </form>
        <section class="results hidden">
          <h2>Look at this dog!</h2>
          <img class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe `console.log(responseJson.message);`? That’s the property you’re inserting into the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';

function getDogImage() {
  fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => 
      displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson.message);
  //replace the existing image with the new one
  $('.results-img').replaceWith(
    `<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
  )
  //display the results section
  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getDogImage();
  });
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dog API Example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dog API: A Simple Example</h1>

        <form>
          <input type="submit" value="Get a dog pic!">
        </form>
        <section class="results hidden">
          <h2>Look at this dog!</h2>
          <img class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed one line of code. Where it does the `console.log(responseJson);` I changed it to `console.log(responseJson.message);`. I think that's what you're asking for